# result expanded to maximum (more) on wolfram alpha query

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

I am using mathematica to query wolfram alpha for a query. for that purpose I use:

```
WolframAlpha["prime minister of france", "PodPlaintext"]
```

I took the options from here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html

My problem is that I need info that is hidden at first and is located under the `more` option on the page. I was unable to find a way to query the full data (after more was clicked) from the mathematica.

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters this problem in the future, I will post the answer in case someone else will have this problem. You have to use the more option combined with asynchronous and change the timeout:

```
WolframAlpha["prime minister of france", Asynchronous -> True, 
  PodStates -> {"More"}, TimeConstraint -> 20000]
```